# Changing the pitch of a sound effect (SFX) in iOS. (Audio playback)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a sound effect that I play on a certain event in the game. When the player chains a few of these events together the same sound may play from 1 to 4 times in a row.

Its hard to find sfx that increase in pitch but are the same sound effect, so I was wondering is there a trick/method in iOS that you can use that will play a sound file but change the pitch(correct term?) of the sound while playing?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: You can use OpenAL to pitch shift.  See this Question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364901/ios-pitch-shifting-piping-output-from-openal-into-a-buffer